# "I need him to get washed" — what is wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice

I said that sentence, implying that a small boy from the next door is kinda stinky. But now I do not know if it is correct to say that.

> I need him to get washed.

Google 0 hits.

Comment: Not every single possible sentence is on Google. Yet. However, googling for "I need * to get washed" or "I need him to get" do return plenty of results.

Comment: It is clumsy. _He needs to get washed_ or _I need to get him washed_ (if you are responsible for him), but replace _to get washed_ with _to take a bath/shower_, and it sounds better in my opinion

Comment: @mplugjan: What about, "I need him to get washed up" (so we can sit down for dinner on time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason why your sentence is unidiomatic (it's certainly not ungrammatical) is that it implies that what *you* need or want is something that is under the control of the boy or his parents, and has nothing to do with you. *I need to get him washed* would be perfectly normal, though it would conjure up a picture of your turning the garden hose on him.

The shortage of hits may also be because 'get washed' is a passive construction, not often applied to able-bodied human beings. Cars get washed; humans take a bath or wash themselves. It appears that this lad needs his parents to wash him or somebody to turn a hose on him; but thankfully this is a rare situation in most communities.

Comment: It seems to me that the phrase "I need him to (do or decide on something)" is very common. It turns up 20 million hits in Google. So needing someone to do something that is under their control is a common need and not the reason why the sentence in question is "wrong". See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you say *"I need him to ...",* usually the thing you need him to do is something which he does himself. And when you say *"get washed",* usually the thing or person getting washed isn't washing it- or themself. So

> I need to get him washed,

would be fine for a small child who doesn't wash himself, and

> I need him to get dressed,

is fine, but only for somebody who dresses himself. But with

> I need him to get washed,

the two verbs *"need"* and *"get"* have incompatible agency requirements, yielding a subtly unidiomatic English sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In some sentences *to get washed* is a passive construction with an explicit or unstated agent. For example:

> The child got washed (by her nanny).

In such passive constructions, *to get* can be replaced by *to be*:

*The child was washed (by her nanny).*

But *to get washed* can also mean, simply, *to wash*:

> I always get washed before breakfast. = I always wash before
>   breakfast.

Decontextualised, the OP's sentence *I need him to get washed* is grammatically unobjectionable, but it is ambiguous. For me, the second usage is more likely and can be imagined in a conversation between a photographer on a busy schedule and the agent of a film star who is still in bed:

> I need him to get up, get washed, get shaved, get dressed and get down
>   here by 10 o'clock.

Comment: Then there's the third possibility with this sentence: I can't get out of bed without my care worker. I need him to get washed. (ie In order for me to be able to wash, I need his help.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean. But if you are implying that he needs a bath, you can say:

> He stinks. He needs to take a bath. He needs a bath.
>
> He needs to wash himself. *less idiomatic.*
>
> He needs to clean himself.

Comment: Well, yes, I thought this would mean "I need him to take a bath". Why "get washed" does not work here? Isn't it like "I need him to get more involved"? Or "I need him to get ready".

Comment: Nothing is wrong with "get washed." But it's less idiomatic.

Comment: "He needs a bath" or "He needs a wash". There are many idiomatic ways of rephrasing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would paraphrase that sentence as, e.g.:

> (Before I can take my dad, who is suffering from a stroke and unable
>   to wash himself, to see the doctor,) I need him to (stop making a fuss
>   and allow himself to) get washed (by his wife).

Not the most elegant way to phrase that meaning, certainly, but definitely not wrong or impossible.

**Explanation**:

It seems to me that the phrase "I need him to (do or decide on something)" is very common. It turns up 20 million hits in Google. So needing someone to do something that is under their control is a common need and not the reason why the sentence in question is "wrong".

The "problem" here is in the contradiction between needing someone to decide on an action (which implies a certain level of mental maturity and phyisical ability on that person's part, else he wouldn't be able to comply, and expecting him to would be stupid on your part) and that person "getting washed", i.e. having a third party wash him (which implies a lack of mental maturity or physical ability, e.g. a small child or a mentally ill person).

So in fact you say that you expect someone, who cannot wash himself, to decide to let himself be washed. That is of course a possible scenario, but not what we would expect under normal everyday circumstances, therefor that sentence feels wrong (at least without a fitting context).